# Setting the download attribute for link using javascript works partially

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the download attribute of a link, that gets triggered after a click by the user, then a timer runs for 10 seconds, then the file gets downloaded automatically.
When the users click the Click here button, the download attribute gets changed , but when it automatically downloads after a time, the download attribute is not being set.
This is the code.

```
const download = document.querySelector('.download-btn');
const countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown');
const pleaseWaitText = document.querySelector('.pleaseWait-text');
const manualDownloadText = document.querySelector('.manualDownload-text');
const manualDownloadLink = document.querySelector('.manualDownload-link');
var timeLeft = 10;

download.addEventListener('click', () => {
download.style.display = "none";
countdown.innerHTML = `Download will begin automatically in <span>${timeLeft}</span> seconds`;

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function timeCount() {
timeLeft--;
countdown.innerHTML = `Download will begin automatically in <span>${timeLeft}</span> seconds`;

if (timeLeft <= 0) {
  clearInterval(downloadTimer);

  pleaseWaitText.style.display = "block";
  let download_href = "https://tuqut.com/jsdn12enda21.pdf";

  window.location.href = download_href;
  manualDownloadLink.href = download_href;
  manualDownloadLink.setAttribute("download", "work.pdf");


  setTimeout(() => {
    pleaseWaitText.style.display = "none";
    manualDownloadText.style.display = "block";
  }, 1000);
}
}, 1000);
});
```

This is the html code

```
<div class="download-container">
<a href="#" class="download-btn">Download files <i class="fas fa- 
download"></i></a>
<div class="countdown"></div>
<div class="pleaseWait-text">Please wait ...</div>
<div class="manualDownload-text">
If the download didn't start automatically, <a href="#" class="manualDownload-link" target="_top" download="work.pdf">click here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please attach html code also

Comment: Why are you redirecting to a new page?

Comment: I mean what is the use of `window.location.href` in the code?

Comment: That has the url where the file needs to be downloaded